# How to get the line count in a string using .NET (with any line break)

Tags: c#, .net, string

I need to **count the number of lines in a string**. Any line break can be character can be present in the string (CR, LF or CRLF).

```
So possible new line chars:
* \n
* \r
* \r\n
```

For example, with the following input:

```
This is [\n]
an string that [\r]
has four [\r\n]
lines
```

The method should return 4 lines. Do you know any built in function, or someone already implemented it?

```
static int GetLineCount(string input)
{
   // could you provide a good implementation for this method?
   // I want to avoid string.split since it performs really bad
}
```

NOTE: Performance is important for me, because I could read large strings.

Comment: if you are using large strings you are already loosing perfomance as you will manuplate it in other data aswell. go with stream in such case where you can have one time operation on each byte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int count = 0;
int len = input.Length;
for(int i = 0; i != len; ++i)
  switch(input[i])
  {
    case '\r':
      ++count;
      if (i + 1 != len && input[i + 1] == '\n')
        ++i;
      break;
    case '\n':
    // Uncomment below to include all other line break sequences
    // case '\u000A':
    // case '\v':
    // case '\f':
    // case '\u0085':
    // case '\u2028':
    // case '\u2029':
      ++count;
      break;
  }
```

Simply scan through, counting the line-breaks, and in the case of `\r` test if the next character is `\n` and skip it if it is.

> Performance is important for me, because I could read large strings.

If at all possible then, avoid reading large strings at all. E.g. if they come from streams this is pretty easy to do directly on a stream as there is no more than one-character read-ahead ever needed.

Here's another variant that doesn't count newlines at the very end of a string:

```
int count = 1;
int len = input.Length - 1;
for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  switch(input[i])
  {
    case '\r':
    if (input[i + 1] == '\n')
    {
      if (++i >= len)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
    goto case '\n';
        case '\n':
        // Uncomment below to include all other line break sequences
        // case '\u000A':
        // case '\v':
        // case '\f':
        // case '\u0085':
        // case '\u2028':
        // case '\u2029':
          ++count;
          break;      
  }
```

This therefore considers `""`, `"a line"`, `"a line\n"` and `"a line\r\n"` to each be one line only, and so on.

Comment: You missed carriage-return next line (`\r\u0085`) combo.

Comment: @leppie I restricted the list to the newline function as defined in Unicode.

Answer (score 2):

Your string is from a file ?

I think this one do the job and do it pretty fast :

```
int count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
```

from :
[How to get Number Of Lines without Reading File To End](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7556171/how-to-get-number-of-lines-without-reading-file-to-end)

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex.Matches(input, "\n|\r|\n\r").Count
```

Answer (score 1):

What about [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557002/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-count-newlines-in-a-large-net-string)

the simple

```
private static int Count4(string s)
{
    int n = 0;
    foreach( var c in s )
    {
        if ( c == '\n' ) n++;
    }
    return n+1;
}
```

should be very fast, even with larger strings... numerous other algorithms have been tested there. What speaks against this implementation? If you don`t extend to use parallel execution I would try this very simple approach.

Comment: This is correct; I believe in keeping things simple. The assumption is if you ever see a \n you increase the count;

Answer (score 1):

Completely manual implementation: (You aren't going to be much faster then this)

```
public static int GetLineCount(string input)
{
    int lineCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (input[i])
        {
            case '\r':
                {
                    if (i + 1 < input.Length)
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (input[i] == '\r')
                        {
                            lineCount += 2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lineCount++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        lineCount++;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case '\n':
                lineCount++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example similar to how Microsoft does it while reading lines from a file:

```
int numberOfLines = 0;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path, encoding))
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        numberOfLines += 1;
```

For reference/reading:
 http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,8d10107b7a92c5c2 http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,675b2259e8706c26

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the number of lines you should count only `\n` as `\r` means a carriage return and doesn't advance to the new line:

```
static int GetLineCount(string input)
{
    return input.Count(c => c == '\n');
}
```